# how to use ShellExecuteEx to run an application on windows ce?

Tags: c++, windows-ce

I am using this code:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = {0};
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpFile = _T("\\test\\WindowsCE\\test.exe");      
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = _T("");   
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL; 
ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
```

I have a program test.exe in the specified directory, but it gives me an error: Cannot find 'test' (or one of its componenet). Make sure the path and filename....
in a windows CE Device with an SD CArd, what could be the path???

Comment: Can you actually see \\test\\WindowsCE\\test.exe on the device?  Can you navigate to it and run it?  It really sounds like your path is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Ususally the path for an SD card is `\\Storage Card` - you have to use the full path. You can just navigate to the file through ActiveSync or in the device itself and see the path you used to get there.

The path you specify means that under the root "folder" (My Device) there is a folder named `test` and under that a folder named `WindowsCE` and under tht you have the file.

Comment: There are other ways. For instance, if the executing program itself is also located on the SD card, you can get the module path. (`GetModuleFileName(NULL, buf, MAX_PATH)` returns a full path.)

Comment: True, but still my answer stands and does not deserve a -1 vote.